# Why .NET 4.8 is recommended version despite 4.8.1 latest version available

Tags: .net, .net-4.8

Looking at the available .NET Frameworks, `4.8.1` is the latest. However `4.8` is `recommended` by Microsoft [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework). I am curious why is that. Is `4.8.1` in beta or something? I couldn't find any information about that.

[image]

Comment: It is only available for recent Windows versions, no support for Server2019 being the most onerous.  Forcing your customer to update their OS is not recommended.

Comment: Where do you see the OS requirement for the framework version?

Comment: Just google ".net 4.8.1", takes you [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-framework-481/)

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. How can I mark this an answer :)

Comment: @HansPassant Apparently [Windows Server 2022 is free for Windows Server 2019 users](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowserver/forum/all/windows-server-free-upgrade-costs-from-windows/9c06469c-1c22-42f8-8297-806a96c34399), which softens the blow.

Answer (score 23):

4.8.1 is not supported on older windows version but 4.8 is supported. (strange decision for a minor version like this)
(even windows 10 is only supported from specific build 20H2)

Comment: Strange indeed, especially considering how insignificant the changes are: https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet/blob/main/releases/net481/dotnet481-changes.md

Comment: @NeilLaslett  "includes native support for the Arm64 architecture" not so insignificant at all to support on all OS's

Comment: .NET Framework 4.8.1 also supports .NET Standard 2.1. Also, it supports newer version of C# language (I suspect C#10, because I can use file-scoped namespaces), where .NET Framework 4.8 is limited to C# 7.3.

Comment: @Nenad That is untrue: [.NET Framework 4.8.1 is only compliant with .NET Standard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-1) and _not_ .NET Standard 2.1. You also cannot use C# 8.0 or higher with .NET 4.8.1 unless you use multi-targeting (which works just fine with .NET Framework 4.7.x and 4.8.0 - and not just only 4.8.1).

Answer (score -2):

The recommendation has been changed in the meantime: Microsoft no longer recommends using the legacy version of the .NET Framework at all. Instead, they recommend using the rewritten version previously known as ".NET Core"

Source: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework.

[image: Screenshot of Download .NET Framework page on Microsoft]

Comment: not sure why the downvote - but the recommendation is not "not to use it at all". it's to use dot net core in new projects. there are millions of code written for the old framework and there is no reason to drop it yet.

Comment: @Dani Thank you for the clarification.. I see your point, but I do not read it that way. To me, when Microsoft says 'we recommend NOT to use .NET Framework, unless you have to` it does mean: "Use it only if you have to, but we do not recommend it". After all "recommended" tag is now removed from .NET Framework and put next to .NET Core download.

Comment: @Nenad your answer is misleading, because it can easily be interpreted as Microsoft abandoning the .Net ecosystem entirely. The only evidence to the contrary is in the screenshot you posted.

Comment: @Dreamer Would it be clear, if I write: "Microsoft does not recommended to use .NET Framework at all. It recommends .NET (Core)"?

Comment: @Nenad Not even that; as Microsoft actually recommends targeting .NET Framework 4.x _instead of_ .NET 6+ for "real" long-term support, as .NET Framework 4.8.x will be supported through the entire life of Windows Server 2022 through to at least the year 2032, while support for .NET 8 ends in 2026 - so ISVs who don't want on the upgrade treadmill should stick to 4.8.x.

Comment: @Dai Can you provide us with any source for the claim that Microsoft recommends staying on .NET 4.x for "very long time" support? This contradicts points 1. and 2. on Microsoft's official .NET Framework download page that I linked in the answer.

Comment: @Nenad I've reviewed the current guidance and if you take their docs at face value then yes, you are correct: [MS does seem to be recommending "_new .NET_" over .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/dotnet-core#:~:text=we%20encourage%20you%20to%20consider%20modernizing%20your%20apps%20to%20leverage%20modern%20.NET); though (and not to diminish that point) [in another document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server) MS recommends .NET Framework over _new .NET_ for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @Nenad ...but I _could swear_ I saw an official document (or perhaps a blog post?) where .NET Framework 4.x was recommended over _new .NET_ for applications needing decade-long support lifecycles (on the basis that Windows LTSC and WS2022 ships with .NET Framework 4.8 and their support lifecycles are typicall 10 years+).

Comment: @Dai To a degree it makes sense, that you are going to get critical fixes for a single framework version longest for .NET Framework 4.x. But at the same time, ecosystem around the apps is changing, browser security, web standards, tls/ssl... I doubt that MS is going to invest even minimum into this. Also note that recommendation in [.NET vs. .NET Framework for server apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server) is now almost 2 years old. However, it's valuable different perspective. Thank you for pointing it out.